# Collapsing previously expanded Group, when new Group has been expanded in ExpandableListView

Tags: android

I'm using ExpandableListView. i have a around 100 groups in the list, and 10-15 childrens for each group.

now my problem is, whenever i expand a new Group , i want the previously expanded group to be closed. is there a way to do this. Please anyone tell me whether it is possible to do this..

Thank u

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the ExpandableListView.OnGroupExpandListener. Maintain the previously expanded groupPosition and use collapseGroup(groupPosition) to close the group.

Comment: so you mean to say i have to keep the previously expanded group position . and collapse that . on new group expand ,right. thats the good idea, thank u

Comment: @Karan how to get previous collapse Group position.any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Very well, we have to maintain previous group integer by final or static variable

Comment: Please, add some explanation with your answer, or example

Answer (score 0):

```
expandableList.setOnGroupExpandListener(new OnGroupExpandListener() {
    int previousItem = -1;

    @Override
    public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
        if(groupPosition != previousItem ) {
            expandableList.collapseGroup(previousItem );
        }
        previousItem = groupPosition;
    }
});
```